# Saving coordinates of specific pixel values from .mat file

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a `.mat` file in MATLAB. It's dimensions are `1040x1392`.

In this picture, I want to save all the coordinates of the cells whose values are greater than some `x` and less than some `y`. I am not able to find any efficient way to do this other than brute force checking each pixel.

I am aware of the `nnz()` function that returns how many pixels there are of a certain value. However, I'm unable to find an efficient way to solve my particular situation. I thought of using `[bwlabel][1]` to do this, however, this gives me all the connected components and I would still have to manually go through to see which connected components I want to keep.

I also tried `[r, c] = find(matrix > 2);` but this returned two variables of sizes far greater than the size of the matrix.

How to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of matlab's `find()` function.

```
m = load('myMatFile.mat');

[row, col] = find(x<m & m<y);
```

Just replace `myMatFile.mat` by your .mat file. Feel free to ask any questions if you need more help on this.

Comment: OOps, I just posted that in my question as well. When I tried find(), my `r` and `c` variables are of size `222421x1`

Comment: or perhaps it's treating it as one large array? I think that's probably my problem. In which case,  my question becomes, how do I preserve the row and column information?

Comment: @nini Thats not a problem. each pair of values in r and c gives you the coordinates of a point that meets your condition. For example [r(1), c(1)] is the first point that meets your condition, [r(2), c(2)] is the second point and... And since your image is of size 1040*1392, your image is made of (1040*1392=1447680) points. So your answer's size is not greater than the size of your matrix (1447680>222421).

Comment: So, if I input [r(10000), c(10000)], what coordinate would that be?

Comment: @nini r(10000) will show the coordinate of the row and c(10000) will show the coordinate of the column.

Comment: Right, however, I only have 1040 rows. So how is this possible?

Comment: It's better to do *coordinates = [r, c];* Then you will have a matrix of 222421*2 where each row will show you the coordinate of one point.

Comment: @nini Well there might be more than 1 point in each row that meets your condition. Just look at your r vector. I'm sure you won't find a value greater than 1040.